# Promise used for concatanation of array from different arrays

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, angular-promise

I want to construct an array with the help of 3 other arrays. I am using JS promise for this purpose but not able to get the implementation right. 
SO what I basically want to do is to populate an array first.

```
let getPlacePromise = function() {
      return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        this.getplaceArray= this.getfilterPlaces(inputdata);
        resolve("got places\n" ); 
      });
  };

  let getTransporterPromise= function(message) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
      this.getTransporterArray= this.getfilterTransporter(inputdata);
      resolve(message+"got Transporter"); 
    });
  }; 

  let getVehiclePromise = function(message) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
      this.getVehicleArray= this.getfilterVehicles(inputdata);
      resolve(message+"got vehicle"); 
    });
  };

  getPlacePromise().then(function(result){
      return getTransporterPromise(result);
  }).then(function(result){
      return getVehiclePromise(result);
  }).then(function(result){
    this.AllDropdownValues= this.getTransporterArray.concat(this.getVehicleArray);
  });
```

I know this code should have errors. I am not able to come up with the right implementation. I want **getplaceArray** to populate first than only the other other arrays should be complete. Is it possible to call function inside promises. The error I was getting here was **getplaceArray, getTransporterArray, getVehicleArray** are undefined.

getfilterTransporter function:

```
getfilterTransporter(autocompleteInputData) {

var k= this.checkRegex(autocompleteInputData);
this.getfilteredTransporter= this.filterTransporters(k);
return this.formatTransporterValue(this.getfilteredTransporter);
```

}

getfilterVehicle :

```
getfilterVehicles(autocompleteInputData) {

  var k= this.checkRegex(autocompleteInputData);
    this.getfilteredVehicle= this.filterVehicles(k);
    return this.formatVehicleValue(this.getfilteredVehicle);
}
```

getfilterPlace

```
getfilterPlaces(autocompleteInputData) {
  if (autocompleteInputData == '' || typeof(autocompleteInputData) == 'object') 
  return null;
  this.placeData.getPlacesFromPig(autocompleteInputData)
  .subscribe(response => {
     return this.formatPigResponse(response);
   }); 

}
```

**Edit** :

Modified the answers a bit. Rest are working but **this.getfilterPlaces** which has a subscribe method running inside it to populate data is not working.

```
let a=[], b=[],c=[];
    a=  this.getfilterPlaces(inputdata);
    b= this.getfilterTransporter(inputdata);
    c= this.getfilterVehicles(inputdata);

    let getplaceArray = [],
  getTransporterArray = [],
  getVehicleArray = [];

let getPlacePromise = function () {
  const self = this;
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    getplaceArray = a;
    resolve("got places\n");
  });
};

let getTransporterPromise = function (message) {
  const self = this;
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    getTransporterArray =  b
    resolve(message + "got Transporter");
  });
};

let getVehiclePromise = function (message) {
  const self = this;
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    getVehicleArray = c
    resolve(message + "got vehicle");
  });
};

getPlacePromise().then(function (result) {
  return getTransporterPromise(result);
}).then(function (result) {
  return getVehiclePromise(result);
}).then(function (result) {
  var AllDropdownValues = getTransporterArray.concat(getVehicleArray).concat(getplaceArray);
  console.log(AllDropdownValues);
});
```

**The answer is** 
use of async and await.Below is the code.

```
async function getfilterPlaces(autocompleteInputData) {
  if (autocompleteInputData == '' || typeof(autocompleteInputData) == 'object') 
    return null;
  return this.placeData.getPlacesFromPig(autocompleteInputData)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => this.formatPigResponse(response));
}
```

while calling the function filterAllComponent(inputdata) :

```
async function filterAllComponent(inputdata) {
  let a=[], b=[], c=[];
  a = await this.getfilterPlaces(inputdata);
  b = this.getfilterTransporter(inputdata);
  c = this.getfilterVehicles(inputdata);
[...]
```

Comment: are any of the `this.getfilter*` functions **asynchronous** ?

Comment: No there are not.

Comment: so, why are you even bothering with Promises?

Comment: Oh, I see the problem ... `this` inside `return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){` is not the `this` you think `this` is

Comment: `getplaceArray, getTransporterArray, getVehicleArray` all 3 have different scopes.

Comment: I want to populate an array with all other three arrays. But place needs more time to populate than other two. So I want getplaceArray to populate first than only others.

Comment: well, even then, the code you posted doesn't wait for anything - I think you've misunderstood promises

Comment: what and How do I define the scope @RahulSharma

Comment: @JaromandaX  if I want the result I am looking for how should I implement it. When I call all 3 functions together than getplaceArray is taking longer so my array concatanation remains incomplete.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: @UDGogs when you do `this.getVehicleArray` it refers current function this not global this and you have fix `this.getfilterVehicles` also because I can't see any getfilterVehicles function in the same scope.

Comment: `how should I implement it` - as far as the asynchronous code goes, *unknown* - because you've not shown `getfilter*` code

Comment: @UDGogs can you add `getfilterVehicles,getfilterPlaces,getfilterTransporter` function also?

Comment: @RahulSharma getfilterVehicles is just returning the data it has extracted from the backend API.

Comment: @JaromandaX, I have edited the questions and added the other functions.

Comment: @RahulSharma I edited the question and added the functions

Comment: @UDGogs check my answer that might help.

Comment: @RahulSharma using getfilterPlaces(inputdata);  without this. is throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let getplaceArray = [],
  getTransporterArray = [],
  getVehicleArray = [];

let getPlacePromise = function () {
  const self = this;
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    getplaceArray = self.getfilterPlaces(inputdata);
    resolve("got places\n");
  });
};

let getTransporterPromise = function (message) {
  const self = this;
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    getTransporterArray = self.getfilterTransporter(inputdata);
    resolve(message + "got Transporter");
  });
};

let getVehiclePromise = function (message) {
  const self = this;
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    getVehicleArray = self.getfilterVehicles(inputdata);
    resolve(message + "got vehicle");
  });
};

getPlacePromise().then(function (result) {
  return getTransporterPromise(result);
}).then(function (result) {
  return getVehiclePromise(result);
}).then(function (result) {
  this.AllDropdownValues = getTransporterArray.concat(getVehicleArray);
});
```

Comment: `this is not required` - you assume to know much about the OP's unwritten code!

Comment: @RahulSharma not working. I have modified the function a bit. check my edit. Rest are working but getfilterPlaces is still not coming. I am sharing the exact function respponsible for populating getfilterPlaces.

Comment: try this `getTransporterArray.concat(getVehicleArray).concat(getplaceArray)`

Comment: done that. check my edit. the two data is coming but not the getfilterPlaces

Comment: @UDGogs I think no need of promise because you are not doing anything inside that.

Comment: @UDGogs are you getting the value of a,b, c?

Comment: @RahulSharma I have updated the anwer with the solution I got. Have a look.